# Using regexp in assertEquals() does not work

Tags: java, regex, selenium, assert, selenium-webdriver

I'm having problems with using regexp in my assertEquals() statement. This is the statement.

```
Assert.assertEquals("regexp:*TST-*[0-9]{5}", driver.getTitle());
```

But I get this error:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[regexp:*TST-*[0-9]{5}]> but was:<[[#TST-23570] This is the new summary]>
```

It looks like the regexp is just a string that is being compared. What am I missing?

Comment: Where did you see the fact that you can just use "regexp:" in an assertEquals?

Comment: @Falmarri - I was wondering the same thing :) (+1)

Comment: I understand you're just learning so my comment is really meant to pick on you or anything (and I doubt @Falmarri's was either) - it really is just more of "where did you get that from". In other words, if you got it from somewhere then we'd have to grab out pitchforks and light the web site afire ;) (jk)

Comment: I know. The problem is I searched for two days and didn't find any place that gave me an example of what I was trying to do. I knew I was doing it wrong so I asked for directions. I know we don't like to "ask for directions", we rather drive around in circles.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're actually **using** the regex. It seems like maybe this is what you're trying to do?

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().matches("*TST-*[0-9]{5}"));
```

EDIT #1:

It also seems like your regex might not be quite right, try:

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.getTitle().matches(".*TST-\\d{5}.*"));
```

Comment: Thanks, that works great. All I needed was an example. Now I get it.

Comment: If that's what you needed do you mind upvoting and\or accepting this answer? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You're asserting the two Strings are the same. In your case you're trying to check that your title is equal to "regexp:*TST-*[0-9]{5}", and not the regexp.

You maybe want to do this:

```
assert_true(driver.getTitle().matches("*TST-*[0-9]{5}"));
```

[http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)](http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29)